How can I design a heart-pulse-sensing circuit using a BPW34 photodiode?
I tried to build this circuit that I found online:

After I built it, I don't think it was working properly. I tried measuring the op amp output with a multimeter, it was very small (below 0.300v) and unstable.
I tried a different circuit, a transimpedance amplifier as shown below:

It seems to give more reasonable results, although I am not sure if this would be the best design for a pulse sensor since it is generic. I don't have much experience in electronics and I hope to get some guidance on how I can make a simple yet effective pulse sensor.

You do realize that the output will be pulses rather than DC, right?  Your voltmeter won't be able to tell you much about the output.  Voltmeters are made to measure constant signals, not pulsing signals.

@JRE Yeah I honestly wish I had an oscilloscope to view the output with. Actually, the signal is unstable and very low even when I shine light directly towards the photodiode (without placing my finger). I do realize that using a multimeter isn't the best idea, but I guess it's good for getting a sense of the average value of the output, right?

The first circuit reacts only to changes in brightness - it cannot show you a response to a steady light.

Have you got a PC or an Android phone?  You can connect the microphone input of either one (through a resistor) to your circuit and use an audio recording program (or a sound card oscillscope program) to see the circuit output.

@JRE I tried to visualize the output with an Arduino before. The method you mentioned is great, but it unfortunately don't work on my pc because I really can't get it to read the mic input of the headphone jack.


I tried measuring the op amp output with a multimeter, it was [...] unstable.

If your pletysmograph works correctly, is on your finger, and has a flat line output, it suggests clinical death. So the instability is definitely a good thing :)
First of all, the LED should blink when things are working. The circuit you have found is not the best, but it should work for the purpose. Make sure your hands are warm when playing with pletysmography. Cold hands tend to have very little signal at the fingertip due to local vasoconstriction.
You'll also want to post a picture of how you have connected things, because it's likely your construction can make it not work in spite of having the same schematic. The photodiode and the op-amp must be very close - on the same PCB really, ideally within a fraction of an inch of each other. Otherwise the op-amp will be mostly picking up mains and other interference. The construction details matter a lot in the circuit and the schematic doesn't capture it.
You'll want to look at the output using an oscilloscope - even a most basic hand-held cheap one will do. Or capture the output with an Arudino, print out the instantaneous values, and visualize them using the signal viewer built into the IDE.
You can also look at the output using an analog voltmeter/multimeter. The needle should be fast enough to clearly visualize pulsation, especially when you're at rest and calm.
